# Add label nodes next to a node and make them close by

Tags: graphviz, dot

The goal is to render an org-chart, where certain individuals have extra colored "labels" attached to them, representing their role in the scenario. Those labels are supposed to be directly to the left of the individual.

By making the individual and their labels part of a sub-graph, and then telling it that the labels and the person node are all `{rank=same;...}`, I was able to force the labels to appear where I wanted them.

However, there is a huge distance between the labels and the node that they are annotating.  Nothing I have tried seems to fix it.

How do I make it so that the "label" nodes are as close to the node they are supposed to label as they are to one another?

```
digraph scenario {
    outputorder=edgesfirst
    rankdir=TB
    graph [ splines=true ]

    subgraph cluster_spec {
        ranksep="0.25 equally"
        style="filled";
        bgcolor="#f7f7f7";
        node [ 
            style="filled",
            fillcolor="#f7f7f7",
            fontname="sans-serif",
            fontsize="10",
            shape=circle,
            width="0.75in",
            fixedsize="shape",
            color="black"
        ]
        manager   [ label="manager",   fillcolor="#00a000", fontcolor="#ffffff" ];
        accessor  [ label="accessor",  fillcolor="#a00000", fontcolor="#ffffff" ];
        submitter [ label="submitter", fillcolor="#ffff00", fontcolor="#000000" ];
        owner     [ label="owner",     fillcolor="#0000a0", fontcolor="#ffffff" ];
        backup    [ label="backup",    fillcolor="#a000a0", fontcolor="#ffffff" ];
{rank=same; "submitter" -> "accessor" [ color="#808080", dir="both" ]}
"manager" -> "submitter" [ color="black" ]
"owner" -> "submitter" [ color="black" ]
{rank=same; "submitter" -> "backup" [ color="#808080", dir="both" ]}
"manager" -> "accessor" [ color="black" ]
"owner" -> "accessor" [ color="black" ]
{rank=same; "accessor" -> "backup" [ label="same", color="red:green", dir="both" ]}
{rank=same; "manager" -> "owner" [ label="same", color="red:green", dir="both" ]}
"manager" -> "backup" [ color="black" ]
"owner" -> "backup" [ color="black" ]
    }
    subgraph cluster_final {
        color=white;
        ranksep="0.25 equally"
        nodesep="0.125"
        node [ 
            fontname="sans-serif"
            shape=circle,
            style="filled",
            fillcolor="#e7e7e7",
            width="1.5in",
            fixedsize=shape,
        ]
        edge [
            color="#000080",
            headclip=true,
            tailclip=true
        ]

        subgraph "cluster_emma-7246-roles" {
            { rank=same;
                "emma-7246-submitter" [ shape="cds", label="submitter", style="filled", fillcolor="#ffff00", height="0.75in", width="1.5in", fontcolor="#000000", fontsize="24"]
 "emma-7246" [ label="emma-7246" ]

                "emma-7246-submitter" -> "emma-7246" [ color="#f0f0f0", len="0.125" ];

            }

        }

        subgraph "cluster_edmund-0712-roles" {
            { rank=same;
                "edmund-0712-accessor" [ shape="cds", label="accessor", style="filled", fillcolor="#a00000", height="0.75in", width="1.5in", fontcolor="#ffffff", fontsize="24"]
 "edmund-0712-backup" [ shape="cds", label="backup", style="filled", fillcolor="#a000a0", height="0.75in", width="1.5in", fontcolor="#ffffff", fontsize="24"]
 "edmund-0712" [ label="edmund-0712" ]

                "edmund-0712-accessor" -> "edmund-0712" [ color="#f0f0f0", len="0.125" ];
 "edmund-0712-backup" -> "edmund-0712" [ color="#f0f0f0", len="0.125" ];

            }

        }

        subgraph "cluster_emma-8949-roles" {
            { rank=same;
                "emma-8949-manager" [ shape="cds", label="manager", style="filled", fillcolor="#00a000", height="0.75in", width="1.5in", fontcolor="#ffffff", fontsize="24"]
 "emma-8949-owner" [ shape="cds", label="owner", style="filled", fillcolor="#0000a0", height="0.75in", width="1.5in", fontcolor="#ffffff", fontsize="24"]
 "emma-8949" [ label="emma-8949" ]

                "emma-8949-manager" -> "emma-8949" [ color="#f0f0f0", len="0.125" ];
 "emma-8949-owner" -> "emma-8949" [ color="#f0f0f0", len="0.125" ];

            }

        }

"edmund-9898" -> "emma-8949"
"emma-8949" -> "edmund-0712"
"emma-8949" -> "emma-7246"
    }
}
```

NOTE: If I take out the first subgraph, then the second one renders the way I expect it to.  Something about the presence of the first subgraph is interfering with the layout and rendering of the second one.

Comment: I'd love to help but am unsure what edge you want to shorten.  When you say "huge distance," what distance are you talking about exactly?  Also, removing subgraph `cluster_spec` didn't seem to make any difference in the rendering of subgraph `cluster_emma-7246-roles`.  Did I read your question right?

Comment: Depends on which version of GraphViz you use.  Try using vis-js.com and render it there.

Comment: I'm using GraphViz 2.38.  Freeware and recommended.  I answer numerous GraphViz questions and many "unsolvable" ones stem from using that site or the python library.

Comment: `dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)`

Comment: So, if you don't see the problem in 2.38, but you see it on vis-js.com, that means it's a bug recently introduced in later versions of GraphVis.